# Trying to grab just the first href in each table row

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab just the first href in each row in an HTML table. Using find_all on the soup object doesn't work because there are multiple tables so I used soup.select() to isolate just that table and work from there but it doesn't seem to be working.

Tried using find_all on the soup object alone, tried looping through the table rows with find() but it said that it returns 'NoneType'.

I Would like to be able to store a list that starts [/players/a/abrinal01.html, "/players/a/acyqu01.html, etc]

```
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_game.html'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "per_game_stats" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the desired data by anchoring the parsing from the outer `div` wrapper with the `id` of `all_per_game_stats`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_game.html').text, 'html.parser')
data = [b.td.a['href'] for b in d.find('div', {'id':'all_per_game_stats'}).table.find_all('tr') if b.td]
```

Output:

```
['/players/a/abrinal01.html', '/players/a/acyqu01.html', '/players/a/adamsja01.html', '/players/a/adamsst01.html', '/players/a/adebaba01.html', '/players/a/adelde01.html', '/players/a/akoonde01.html', '/players/a/aldrila01.html', '/players/a/alkinra01.html', '/players/a/allengr01.html', '/players/a/allenja01.html', '/players/a/allenka01.html', '/players/a/aminual01.html', '/players/a/anderju01.html', '/players/a/anderky01.html', '/players/a/anderry01.html', '/players/a/anderry01.html', '/players/a/anderry01.html', '/players/a/anigbik01.html', '/players/a/antetgi01.html', '/players/a/antetko01.html', '/players/a/anthoca01.html', '/players/a/anunoog01.html', '/players/a/arcidry01.html', '/players/a/arizatr01.html', '/players/a/arizatr01.html', '/players/a/arizatr01.html', '/players/a/augusdj01.html', '/players/a/aytonde01.html', '/players/b/bacondw01.html', '/players/b/baglema01.html', '/players/b/bakerro01.html', '/players/b/bakerro01.html', '/players/b/bakerro01.html', '/players/b/baldwwa01.html', '/players/b/balllo01.html', '/players/b/bambamo01.html', '/players/b/bareajo01.html', '/players/b/barneha02.html', '/players/b/barneha02.html', '/players/b/barneha02.html', '/players/b/bartowi01.html', '/players/b/bateske01.html', '/players/b/batumni01.html', '/players/b/bayleje01.html', '/players/b/baynear01.html', '/players/b/bazemke01.html', '/players/b/bealbr01.html', '/players/b/beaslma01.html', '/players/b/beaslmi01.html', '/players/b/belinma01.html', '/players/b/belljo01.html', '/players/b/bembrde01.html', '/players/b/bendedr01.html', '/players/b/bertada02.html', '/players/b/bertada01.html', '/players/b/beverpa01.html', '/players/b/birchkh01.html', '/players/b/biyombi01.html', '/players/b/bjeline01.html', '/players/b/blakean01.html', '/players/b/bledser01.html', '/players/b/blossja01.html', '/players/b/bogdabo01.html', '/players/b/bogdabo02.html', '/players/b/bogutan01.html', '/players/b/boldejo01.html', '/players/b/bongais01.html', '/players/b/bookede01.html', '/players/b/bouchch01.html', '/players/b/bradlav01.html', '/players/b/bradlav01.html', '/players/b/bradlav01.html', '/players/b/bradlto01.html', '/players/b/breweco01.html', '/players/b/breweco01.html', '/players/b/breweco01.html', '/players/b/bridgmi01.html', '/players/b/bridgmi02.html', '/players/b/briscis01.html', '/players/b/broekry01.html', '/players/b/brogdma01.html', '/players/b/brookdi01.html', '/players/b/brookma01.html', '/players/b/brownbr01.html', '/players/b/brownja02.html', '/players/b/brownlo01.html', '/players/b/brownst02.html', '/players/b/browntr01.html', '/players/b/brunsja01.html', '/players/b/bryanth01.html', '/players/b/bullore01.html', '/players/b/bullore01.html', '/players/b/bullore01.html', '/players/b/burketr01.html', '/players/b/burketr01.html', '/players/b/burketr01.html', '/players/b/burksal01.html', '/players/b/burksal01.html', '/players/b/burksal01.html', '/players/b/burksal01.html', '/players/b/burtode02.html', '/players/b/butleji01.html', '/players/b/butleji01.html', '/players/b/butleji01.html', '/players/c/cabocbr01.html', '/players/c/caldejo01.html', '/players/c/caldwke01.html', '/players/c/canaais01.html', '/players/c/canaais01.html', '/players/c/canaais01.html', '/players/c/canaais01.html', '/players/c/capelca01.html', '/players/c/carrode01.html', '/players/c/carteje01.html', '/players/c/cartevi01.html', '/players/c/cartewe01.html', '/players/c/cartemi01.html', '/players/c/cartemi01.html', '/players/c/cartemi01.html', '/players/c/carusal01.html', '/players/c/casspom01.html', '/players/c/caulewi01.html', '/players/c/caupatr01.html', '/players/c/cavanty01.html', '/players/c/chandty01.html', '/players/c/chandty01.html', '/players/c/chandty01.html', '/players/c/chandwi01.html', '/players/c/chandwi01.html', '/players/c/chandwi01.html', '/players/c/chealjo01.html', '/players/c/chiozch01.html', '/players/c/chrisma01.html', '/players/c/chrisma01.html', '/players/c/chrisma01.html', '/players/c/clarkga01.html', '/players/c/clarkia01.html', '/players/c/clarkjo01.html', '/players/c/collijo01.html', '/players/c/colliza01.html', '/players/c/collida01.html', '/players/c/colsobo01.html', '/players/c/conlemi01.html', '/players/c/connapa01.html', '/players/c/cookqu01.html', '/players/c/couside01.html', '/players/c/covinro01.html', '/players/c/covinro01.html', '/players/c/covinro01.html', '/players/c/crabbal01.html', '/players/c/craigto01.html', '/players/c/crawfja01.html', '/players/c/creekmi01.html', '/players/c/creekmi01.html', '/players/c/creekmi01.html', '/players/c/crowdja01.html', '/players/c/cunnida01.html', '/players/c/curryse01.html', '/players/c/curryst01.html', '/players/d/danietr01.html', '/players/d/davisan02.html', '/players/d/davisde01.html', '/players/d/davised01.html', '/players/d/davisty01.html', '/players/d/dedmode01.html', '/players/d/dekkesa01.html', '/players/d/dekkesa01.html', '/players/d/dekkesa01.html', '/players/d/delgaan01.html', '/players/d/dellama01.html', '/players/d/dellama01.html', '/players/d/dellama01.html', '/players/d/denglu01.html', '/players/d/derozde01.html', '/players/d/derrima01.html', '/players/d/diallch01.html', '/players/d/diallha01.html', '/players/d/dienggo01.html', '/players/d/dinwisp01.html', '/players/d/divindo01.html', '/players/d/doncilu01.html', '/players/d/dorsety01.html', '/players/d/dorsety01.html', '/players/d/dorsety01.html', '/players/d/dotsoda01.html', '/players/d/doziepj01.html', '/players/d/dragigo01.html', '/players/d/drumman01.html', '/players/d/dudleja01.html', '/players/d/dunnkr01.html', '/players/d/duranke01.html', '/players/d/duvaltr01.html', '/players/e/edwarvi01.html', '/players/e/ellenhe01.html', '/players/e/ellenhe01.html', '/players/e/ellenhe01.html', '/players/e/ellinwa01.html', '/players/e/ellinwa01.html', '/players/e/ellinwa01.html', '/players/e/embiijo01.html', '/players/e/ennisja01.html', '/players/e/ennisja01.html', '/players/e/ennisja01.html', '/players/e/eubandr01.html', '/players/e/evansja02.html', '/players/e/evansja01.html', '/players/e/evansja01.html', '/players/e/evansja01.html', '/players/e/evansty01.html', '/players/e/exumda01.html', '/players/f/farieke01.html', '/players/f/farieke01.html', '/players/f/farieke01.html', '/players/f/favorde01.html', '/players/f/feliccr01.html', '/players/f/feltora01.html', '/players/f/fergute01.html', '/players/f/ferreyo01.html', '/players/f/finnedo01.html', '/players/f/forbebr01.html', '/players/f/fournev01.html', '/players/f/foxde01.html', '/players/f/frazime01.html', '/players/f/fraziti01.html', '/players/f/fraziti01.html', '/players/f/fraziti01.html', '/players/f/fredeji01.html', '/players/f/fryech01.html', '/players/f/fultzma01.html', '/players/g/gallida01.html', '/players/g/gallola01.html', '/players/g/garrebi01.html', '/players/g/gasolma01.html', '/players/g/gasolma01.html', '/players/g/gasolma01.html', '/players/g/gasolpa01.html', '/players/g/gasolpa01.html', '/players/g/gasolpa01.html', '/players/g/gayru01.html', '/players/g/georgpa01.html', '/players/g/gibsota01.html', '/players/g/gilesha01.html', '/players/g/gilgesh01.html', '/players/g/goberru01.html', '/players/g/goodwbr01.html', '/players/g/gordoaa01.html', '/players/g/gordoer01.html', '/players/g/gortama01.html', '/players/g/grahade01.html', '/players/g/grahatr01.html', '/players/g/grantje01.html', '/players/g/grantje02.html', '/players/g/grantdo01.html', '/players/g/greenda02.html', '/players/g/greendr01.html', '/players/g/greenge01.html', '/players/g/greenja01.html', '/players/g/greenja01.html', '/players/g/greenja01.html', '/players/g/greenje02.html', '/players/g/griffbl01.html', '/players/h/hamilda02.html', '/players/h/hannadu01.html', '/players/h/hardati02.html', '/players/h/hardati02.html', '/players/h/hardati02.html', '/players/h/hardeja01.html', '/players/h/harklma01.html', '/players/h/harremo01.html', '/players/h/harride01.html', '/players/h/harriga01.html', '/players/h/harrijo01.html', '/players/h/harrito02.html', '/players/h/harrito02.html', '/players/h/harrito02.html', '/players/h/harrian01.html', '/players/h/harrian01.html', '/players/h/harrian01.html', '/players/h/harrian01.html', '/players/h/harrish01.html', '/players/h/hartjo01.html', '/players/h/harteis01.html', '/players/h/hasleud01.html', '/players/h/haywago01.html', '/players/h/hensojo01.html', '/players/h/hernaju01.html', '/players/h/hernawi01.html', '/players/h/hezonma01.html', '/players/h/hicksis01.html', '/players/h/hieldbu01.html', '/players/h/highsha01.html', '/players/h/hilarne01.html', '/players/h/hillge01.html', '/players/h/hillge01.html', '/players/h/hillge01.html', '/players/h/hillso01.html', '/players/h/holidaa01.html', '/players/h/holidjr01.html', '/players/h/holidju01.html', '/players/h/holidju01.html', '/players/h/holidju01.html', '/players/h/hollajo02.html', '/players/h/holliro01.html', '/players/h/holmeri01.html', '/players/h/hoodro01.html', '/players/h/hoodro01.html', '/players/h/hoodro01.html', '/players/h/horfoal01.html', '/players/h/houseda01.html', '/players/h/howardw01.html', '/players/h/huertke01.html', '/players/h/humphis01.html', '/players/h/hunterj01.html', '/players/h/hutchch01.html', '/players/i/ibakase01.html', '/players/i/iguodan01.html', '/players/i/ilyaser01.html', '/players/i/inglejo01.html', '/players/i/ingraan01.html', '/players/i/ingrabr01.html', '/players/i/irvinky01.html', '/players/i/isaacjo01.html', '/players/i/iwundwe01.html', '/players/j/jacksde01.html', '/players/j/jacksfr01.html', '/players/j/jacksja02.html', '/players/j/jacksjo02.html', '/players/j/jacksju01.html', '/players/j/jacksju01.html', '/players/j/jacksju01.html', '/players/j/jacksre01.html', '/players/j/jamesle01.html', '/players/j/jeffeam01.html', '/players/j/jenkijo01.html', '/players/j/jenkijo01.html', '/players/j/jenkijo01.html', '/players/j/jerebjo01.html', '/players/j/johnsal02.html', '/players/j/johnsam01.html', '/players/j/johnsbj01.html', '/players/j/johnsbj01.html', '/players/j/johnsbj01.html', '/players/j/johnsja01.html', '/players/j/johnsst04.html', '/players/j/johnsst04.html', '/players/j/johnsst04.html', '/players/j/johnsty01.html', '/players/j/johnsty01.html', '/players/j/johnsty01.html', '/players/j/johnswe01.html', '/players/j/johnswe01.html', '/players/j/johnswe01.html', '/players/j/jokicni01.html', '/players/j/jonesda03.html', '/players/j/jonesde02.html', '/players/j/jonesja04.html', '/players/j/jonesje01.html', '/players/j/joneste01.html', '/players/j/jonesty01.html', '/players/j/jordade01.html', '/players/j/jordade01.html', '/players/j/jordade01.html', '/players/j/josepco01.html', '/players/k/kaminfr01.html', '/players/k/kanteen01.html', '/players/k/kanteen01.html', '/players/k/kanteen01.html', '/players/k/kennalu01.html', '/players/k/kiddgmi01.html', '/players/k/kingge03.html', '/players/k/klebima01.html', '/players/k/knighbr03.html', '/players/k/knighbr03.html', '/players/k/knighbr03.html', '/players/k/knoxke01.html', '/players/k/korkmfu01.html', '/players/k/kornelu01.html', '/players/k/korveky01.html', '/players/k/korveky01.html', '/players/k/korveky01.html', '/players/k/koufoko01.html', '/players/k/kurucro01.html', '/players/k/kuzmaky01.html', '/players/l/labissk01.html', '/players/l/labissk01.html', '/players/l/labissk01.html', '/players/l/lambje01.html', '/players/l/lavinza01.html', '/players/l/laymaja01.html', '/players/l/leaftj01.html', '/players/l/leeco01.html', '/players/l/leeco01.html', '/players/l/leeco01.html', '/players/l/leeda03.html', '/players/l/lemonwa01.html', '/players/l/lenal01.html', '/players/l/leonaka01.html', '/players/l/leoname01.html', '/players/l/leuerjo01.html', '/players/l/leverca01.html', '/players/l/lillada01.html', '/players/l/linje01.html', '/players/l/linje01.html', '/players/l/linje01.html', '/players/l/livinsh01.html', '/players/l/loftoza01.html', '/players/l/looneke01.html', '/players/l/lopezbr01.html', '/players/l/lopezro01.html', '/players/l/loveke01.html', '/players/l/lowryky01.html', '/players/l/loydjo01.html', '/players/l/lucaska01.html', '/players/l/luwawti01.html', '/players/l/luwawti01.html', '/players/l/luwawti01.html', '/players/l/lydonty01.html', '/players/l/lylestr01.html', '/players/m/machasc01.html', '/players/m/macksh01.html', '/players/m/macksh01.html', '/players/m/macksh01.html', '/players/m/maconda01.html', '/players/m/macurjp01.html', '/players/m/mahinia01.html', '/players/m/makerth01.html', '/players/m/makerth01.html', '/players/m/makerth01.html', '/players/m/marjabo01.html', '/players/m/marjabo01.html', '/players/m/marjabo01.html', '/players/m/markkla01.html', '/players/m/martija01.html', '/players/m/masonfr01.html', '/players/m/matenya01.html', '/players/m/matthwe02.html', '/players/m/matthwe02.html', '/players/m/matthwe02.html', '/players/m/matthwe02.html', '/players/m/mbahalu01.html', '/players/m/mccalta01.html', '/players/m/mccawpa01.html', '/players/m/mccawpa01.html', '/players/m/mccawpa01.html', '/players/m/mccolcj01.html', '/players/m/mccontj01.html', '/players/m/mcderdo01.html', '/players/m/mcgeeja01.html', '/players/m/mcgruro01.html', '/players/m/mckinal01.html', '/players/m/mclembe01.html', '/players/m/mcraejo01.html', '/players/m/meeksjo01.html', '/players/m/mejrisa01.html', '/players/m/meltode01.html', '/players/m/metuch01.html', '/players/m/middlkh01.html', '/players/m/milescj01.html', '/players/m/milescj01.html', '/players/m/milescj01.html', '/players/m/milleda01.html', '/players/m/millema01.html', '/players/m/millspa02.html', '/players/m/millspa01.html', '/players/m/miltosh01.html', '/players/m/mirotni01.html', '/players/m/mirotni01.html', '/players/m/mirotni01.html', '/players/m/mitchdo01.html', '/players/m/mitrona01.html', '/players/m/monkma01.html', '/players/m/monrogr01.html', '/players/m/monrogr01.html', '/players/m/monrogr01.html', '/players/m/monrogr01.html', '/players/m/mooreet01.html', '/players/m/moreler01.html', '/players/m/moreler01.html', '/players/m/moreler01.html', '/players/m/morrija01.html', '/players/m/morrima03.html', '/players/m/morrima02.html', '/players/m/morrima02.html', '/players/m/morrima02.html', '/players/m/morrimo01.html', '/players/m/motiedo01.html', '/players/m/motlejo01.html', '/players/m/mudiaem01.html', '/players/m/murraja01.html', '/players/m/musadz01.html', '/players/m/muscami01.html', '/players/m/muscami01.html', '/players/m/muscami01.html', '/players/m/mykhasv01.html', '/players/m/mykhasv01.html', '/players/m/mykhasv01.html', '/players/n/naderab01.html', '/players/n/nancela02.html', '/players/n/napiesh01.html', '/players/n/netora01.html', '/players/n/niangge01.html', '/players/n/noahjo01.html', '/players/n/noelne01.html', '/players/n/nowitdi01.html', '/players/n/ntilila01.html', '/players/n/nunnaja01.html', '/players/n/nunnaja01.html', '/players/n/nunnaja01.html', '/players/n/nurkiju01.html', '/players/n/nwabada01.html', '/players/o/onealro01.html', '/players/o/oquinky01.html', '/players/o/ojelese01.html', '/players/o/okafoja01.html', '/players/o/okoboel01.html', '/players/o/okogijo01.html', '/players/o/oladivi01.html', '/players/o/olynyke01.html', '/players/o/osmande01.html', '/players/o/oubreke01.html', '/players/o/oubreke01.html', '/players/o/oubreke01.html', '/players/p/pachuza01.html', '/players/p/parkeja01.html', '/players/p/parkeja01.html', '/players/p/parkeja01.html', '/players/p/parketo01.html', '/players/p/parsoch01.html', '/players/p/pattepa01.html', '/players/p/pattoju01.html', '/players/p/paulch01.html', '/players/p/payneca01.html', '/players/p/payneca01.html', '/players/p/payneca01.html', '/players/p/paytoel01.html', '/players/p/paytoga02.html', '/players/p/pinsoth01.html', '/players/p/plumlma01.html', '/players/p/plumlmi01.html', '/players/p/poeltja01.html', '/players/p/pondequ01.html', '/players/p/porteot01.html', '/players/p/porteot01.html', '/players/p/porteot01.html', '/players/p/portibo01.html', '/players/p/portibo01.html', '/players/p/portibo01.html', '/players/p/poweldw01.html', '/players/p/powelno01.html', '/players/p/poythal01.html', '/players/q/qizh01.html', '/players/r/rabbiv01.html', '/players/r/randlch01.html', '/players/r/randlju01.html', '/players/r/redicjj01.html', '/players/r/reedda01.html', '/players/r/reynoca01.html', '/players/r/richajo01.html', '/players/r/richama01.html', '/players/r/riverau01.html', '/players/r/riverau01.html', '/players/r/riverau01.html', '/players/r/robinde01.html', '/players/r/robindu01.html', '/players/r/robingl02.html', '/players/r/robinje01.html', '/players/r/robinmi01.html', '/players/r/rondora01.html', '/players/r/rosede01.html', '/players/r/rosste01.html', '/players/r/roziete01.html', '/players/r/rubiori01.html', '/players/r/russeda01.html', '/players/s/sabondo01.html', '/players/s/sampsbr01.html', '/players/s/sampsja02.html', '/players/s/saricda01.html', '/players/s/saricda01.html', '/players/s/saricda01.html', '/players/s/satorto01.html', '/players/s/schrode01.html', '/players/s/scottmi01.html', '/players/s/scottmi01.html', '/players/s/scottmi01.html', '/players/s/sefolth01.html', '/players/s/seldewa01.html', '/players/s/seldewa01.html', '/players/s/seldewa01.html', '/players/s/sextoco01.html', '/players/s/shamela01.html', '/players/s/shamela01.html', '/players/s/shamela01.html', '/players/s/shumpim01.html', '/players/s/shumpim01.html', '/players/s/shumpim01.html', '/players/s/siakapa01.html', '/players/s/siberjo01.html', '/players/s/simmobe01.html', '/players/s/simmojo02.html', '/players/s/simmojo02.html', '/players/s/simmojo02.html', '/players/s/simmoko01.html', '/players/s/simonan01.html', '/players/s/smartma01.html', '/players/s/smithde03.html', '/players/s/smithde03.html', '/players/s/smithde03.html', '/players/s/smithis01.html', '/players/s/smithjr01.html', '/players/s/smithja02.html', '/players/s/smithja02.html', '/players/s/smithja02.html', '/players/s/smithja02.html', '/players/s/smithzh01.html', '/players/s/snellto01.html', '/players/s/spaldra01.html', '/players/s/spaldra01.html', '/players/s/spaldra01.html', '/players/s/spellom01.html', '/players/s/stausni01.html', '/players/s/stausni01.html', '/players/s/stausni01.html', '/players/s/stephdj01.html', '/players/s/stephla01.html', '/players/s/sumneed01.html', '/players/s/swanica01.html', '/players/s/swanica01.html', '/players/s/swanica01.html', '/players/t/tatumja01.html', '/players/t/teaguje01.html', '/players/t/templga01.html', '/players/t/templga01.html', '/players/t/templga01.html', '/players/t/teodomi01.html', '/players/t/terreja01.html', '/players/t/terryem01.html', '/players/t/terryem01.html', '/players/t/terryem01.html', '/players/t/theisda01.html', '/players/t/thomais02.html', '/players/t/thomakh01.html', '/players/t/thomala01.html', '/players/t/thompkl01.html', '/players/t/thomptr01.html', '/players/t/thornsi01.html', '/players/t/tollian01.html', '/players/t/townska01.html', '/players/t/trentga02.html', '/players/t/trieral01.html', '/players/t/tuckepj01.html', '/players/t/turneev01.html', '/players/t/turnemy01.html', '/players/u/udohek01.html', '/players/u/ulisty01.html', '/players/v/valanjo01.html', '/players/v/valanjo01.html', '/players/v/valanjo01.html', '/players/v/vandeja01.html', '/players/v/vanvlfr01.html', '/players/v/vonleno01.html', '/players/v/vucevni01.html', '/players/w/wadedw01.html', '/players/w/wagnemo01.html', '/players/w/waitedi01.html', '/players/w/walkeke02.html', '/players/w/walkelo01.html', '/players/w/walljo01.html', '/players/w/wallaty01.html', '/players/p/princta02.html', '/players/w/wanambr01.html', '/players/w/warretj01.html', '/players/w/washbju01.html', '/players/w/watanyu01.html', '/players/w/welshth01.html', '/players/w/westbru01.html', '/players/w/whitede01.html', '/players/w/whiteok01.html', '/players/w/whiteha01.html', '/players/w/wiggian01.html', '/players/w/willial03.html', '/players/w/willicj01.html', '/players/w/willijo04.html', '/players/w/willike04.html', '/players/w/willilo02.html', '/players/w/willima02.html', '/players/w/williro04.html', '/players/w/willitr02.html', '/players/w/wilsodj01.html', '/players/w/winslju01.html', '/players/w/woodch01.html', '/players/w/woodch01.html', '/players/w/woodch01.html', '/players/w/wrighde01.html', '/players/w/wrighde01.html', '/players/w/wrighde01.html', '/players/y/yabusgu01.html', '/players/y/youngni01.html', '/players/y/youngth01.html', '/players/y/youngtr01.html', '/players/z/zelleco01.html', '/players/z/zellety01.html', '/players/z/zellety01.html', '/players/z/zellety01.html', '/players/z/zizican01.html', '/players/z/zubaciv01.html', '/players/z/zubaciv01.html', '/players/z/zubaciv01.html']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you be able to break down that list comprehension a little bit in English? I'm a bit of a python newbie and while I see how it works, I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @Acro2142 Glad to help! The comprehension iterates over all `tr` rows of the child `table` under the main `div`. Utilizing `td` as an attribute name finds the first `td` cell which stores the player link. The `a` object can accessed by name and its `href` by its buildin `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a set comprehension to remove duplicates and also I think `nth-of-type` to select the appropriate column reads more cleanly. Using bs4 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_game.html').text, 'html.parser')
links = {i['href'] for i in soup.select('#per_game_stats td:nth-of-type(1) a')}
print(links)
```

You could also use the following css selector:

```
[csk] > a
```